# Categories dropdown with all values selected using wp_dropdown_categories

Tags: categories, dropdown

I'm using this code to get a dropdown list of categories, but **all options are marked as selected**. Therefore, the last option is the one that is displayed as selected by default.

```
<?php wp_dropdown_categories( 
    array( 
        'class' => 'form-control', 
        'show_option_none' => 'Search by category...',
        'hierarchical'     => true,
        'depth'            => 1,
        'hide_empty'       => true,
        'exclude'          => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'NAME',
        'value_field'      => 'slug',
        )
    ); ?>
```

I also tried with the following parameter, but it didn't work.

```
'select' => 0
```

How can I prevent the selected attribute to be assigned to all items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this parameter:

```
'select' => false
```

The solution is in the Wordpress Codex Function Reference for [wp_dropdown_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories/%20wp_dropdown_categories):

> The default value for the selected parameter is 0, but this can cause a dropdown with all terms marked as selected. To fix this, set the selected parameter to false, rather than 0.